# How to decode "SELF-SHIFT" cipher?

Tags: decryption

I try to use the function
$$C_i=E(M_{2i}, M_{2i+1}) = (M_{2i} + M_{2i+1})\bmod 26.$$
to encode **English** text.

For example,

> Plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
> Regrouped Text: TH EQ UI CK BR OW NF OX JU MP SO VE RT HE LA ZY DO G.
> $$
> T = 19, H = 7, (T + H) \bmod 26 = 26 \bmod 26 = 0 = A.\\
> \cdots\\
> (D + O) \bmod 26 = R.
> $$
> Ciphertext: AUCMSKSLDBGZKLLXRG.

Then I'm trying to decode the cipher. Frequency analysis doesn't work, maybe Kasiski examination's variant works.

**There might be many sentences that satisfy the English grammar and can be encoded as the cipher text. It's okay to get only some of them.**

Comment: This cannot be reliably decoded because it loses information. For instance `AA`, `BZ`, `CY`, etc all encode to `A`, so when deciding `A` it's ambiguous what the corresponding plaintext is.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I'm encoding English text, therefore the text must satisfy the English grammar.

Comment: This seems more like a (lossy) encoding method than a cipher, as the latter (usually) involve a key. Given each letter of ciphertext decodes to one of 26 digraphs, it seems plausible that one could use a model trained on natural languages to recover *likely* plaintexts. That is not really part of the field of cryptography though, rather you might want to check existing work in natural language processing. I can imagine that e.g. OCR techniques face related issues.